# How to implement ngOnChanges for input validation on angular 2 without triggering ' Expression has changed after it was checked.' error

Tags: angular, typescript, components

I tried to wrote own custom component that has basic validation with regex that can be given as input to component. Theres two cases, one where form is empty initially (new item form) and another where data is allready there (edit).

Problem is that when i try validate fields after data is initially set, usually i get 'Expression has changed after it was checked.'. I understand why this check is made and why error occurs but i dont simply get it what is the point of 
'ngOnChanges' if i cannot change component state from it? In this case state change is 'isValid' boolean flag which causes component borders to become red.

I have tried following:

- this.changeDetect.detectChanges(), before and after on ngOnChanges.
- change 'text' as getter/setter pair. Move validation logig there. same error. I think this is
  basically the same as ngOnChanges so no surpsise there.
- ngAfterViewInit doesnt validate case where code updates form (for
  example, query from backend ends -> edit form is filled.) Error
  doesn't occur however.
- set changeDetection stragedy as push at @Component decorator.
- timeouts... no change, if i set timeout over 1sec nothing happens, if
  less error occurs. This is probably tied to development mode check
  which seems to occur 1 sec after initial changedetection.

This feels very common and simple use case, and for that reason i think i miss something very simple here.

Example usage:

```
<cx-form-text-input validate=".+" label="Rekisterinumero*" [(text)]="ticket.registerPlate" format="uppercase"></cx-form-text-input>
```

Example component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'cx-form-text-input',
  templateUrl: './form-text-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form-text-input.component.scss']
})
export class FormTextInputComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input()
  public text: string;

  @Output() textChange = new EventEmitter();

  @Input() public validate;

  @Input() public label: string = 'DEFAULT LABEL';

  @Input() public disabled = false;

  @Input() format: string;

  public entry: FormEntry;

  constructor(private form: FormContext, private changeDetect: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.entry = form.Join();
  }

  private applyFormat(text: string): string {
    switch (this.format) {
      case 'uppercase':
        return text.toUpperCase();
      default:
        return text;
    }
  }

  public isDisabled(): boolean {
    return this.disabled || this.form.disabled;
  }

  public keyboardEvent() {
    this.entry.isDirty = true;
    this.text = this.applyFormat(this.text);
    this.validateData();

    this.textChange.emit(this.text);
  }

  private validateData() {
    if (!this.validate) {
      this.entry.isValid = true;
      return;
    }

    if (!this.text) {
      this.entry.isValid = false;
      return;
    }

    this.entry.isValid = !!this.text.match(this.validate);
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    this.validateData(); // The painpoint...
  }
}
```

Error:

```
EXCEPTION: Error in ./EditFormComponent class EditFormComponent - inline template:6:72 caused by: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'.
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'.
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    this.validateData(); // The painpoint...
    this.changeDetect.detectChanges(); // <<<=== invoke change detection at the end of `ngOnChanges` if the model was modified 
  }
```

Comment: Tried that allready, https://i.imgur.com/PnVsfpt.png, no help. So that should work? If so i think theres may be something else in my code that causes it. Or this is bug in angular 2. However i have used from 2.1 -> 2.4 and this still occurs.

Comment: The error message is about `EditFormComponent` and the code in your question shows `FormTextInputComponent`. My answer works only when the change is only affecting the model of the current class (`FormTextInputComponent`). You can try injecting `private appRef: ApplicationRef` and call `this.appRef.tick()`.

Comment: Hmm yes, that is good point! I will check that tomorrow if i can track chain back to EditFormComponent and figure out what causes error there after validation.